Undefined control sequence when using \sfrac
Good evening,
I was wondering if you could help me with making sense of an error I have started encountering. For some reason the LaTeX interpreter no longer recognises the \sfrac command from the xfrac package. Below is the MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

Test~$\sfrac{2}{3}$ test test.

\end{document}

I have reinstalled the package, but to no avail. Have you come across something like that?

You have not said but the error message shows \IfInstanceExistTF  is the undefined command, this is a typo, and an update has already been sent to ctan.

put \let\IfInstanceExistTF\IfInstanceExistsTF before the \usepackage as a workaround, or wait until tomorrow and update your system and it should be fixed.

@DavidCarlisle thank you very much for letting me know!
